# Angular ng-repeat OrderBy breaks when pushing new data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When adding data to an array the new data is not ordered correctly in an ng-repeat.

```
$scope.items.push(newItem);
```

The newItem is instead added to the beginning of the array and not ordered.

Demonstrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqnKt/164/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused because the existing id fields were strings - the new data pushed was an integer. Changing the initial id fields to have integers fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this:

```
  function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.items = [
    {id:2,name:"name2"},//change the id:"2" to id:2
    {id:3,name:"name3"},//change the id:"3" to id:3
    {id:1,name:"name1"},//change the id:"1" to id:1
    {id:4,name:"name4"},//change the id:"4" to id:4
];
var index = 5;
$scope.add = function(item) {
    var newItem = {id: index, name: item};
    $scope.items.push(newItem);
    index++;
};

}
```

"Id" should be integer, so change your declaration of items and change the "id" to int. Hope this will work in your case.